# Split strings in list

Tags: python, list, split

I am creating a list with the files in a folder. The files are named like this: **t1507859_Etappe-02-Alpe-Adria-Trail.svg**. I want to split the strings to get something like: `["t1507859_Etappe-", "02", "-Alpe-Adria-Trail.svg"]`. I want to get back the numbers on the second place of the list I got from the split operation.

```
dirs = os.listdir (path)

[i.split('-', 2)[1] for i in l]

print dirs
```

If i parse this code line by line into the python shell it works but not if I let it run as a module. There I just get the normal dir list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If i parse this code line by line into the python shell it works but not if I let it run as a module. There I just get the normal dir list.

Sure, this is because *you are not assigning the result of the list comprehension to a variable*. Instead, you meant:

```
dirs = os.listdir(path)
dirs = [i.split('-', 2)[1] for i in dirs]
print(dirs)
```